# Что не так при умножении?

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                int multiplication = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    multiplication *= array[i, 1];
                    multiplicationOfNumbers = multiplication;
                } 
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Произведение 1 столбца: " + multiplicationOfNumbers + " ");
```

Comment: Зачем у вас два цикла, если вы берёте один столбец, т.е. цикл нужен только по строкам. Второй цикл не нужен, вы `j` нигде не используете.

Comment: Все равно умножение не правильное получается

Comment: Так вы хоть расскажите, что на что умножить хотите.

Comment: нужно в двумерном массиве умножить 1 столбец между собой

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, пример исходных данных и результата, который должен получиться.

Comment: вот тут код https://pastebin.com/V106avk0

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
int multiplication = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       { 
          multiplication *= array[i, 1];         
       }
Console.WriteLine($"Произведение 1 столбца: {multiplication}");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло